# SQLITE Vlookup in 2 different tables

Tags: sql, sqlite, vlookup

I have 2 tables where 1 bank data other is payment confirmation, I need to perform a lookup.

I have tried few `left join` examples but not able to get the desired output.
I am using `Sqlite3`

Please suggest

**table - Payment_Details**

```
Payment_Date    TranNo      RefNo       ChequeNo
11-Nov-19       tran001     ref001      chq001
11-Nov-19       tran001     ref002      chq005
12-Nov-19       tran003     ref003      chq007
13-Nov-19       tran017     ref001      chq005
```

**Table - Payment_Confirmations**

```
CustomerID      Payment_No      Match_Status        Payment_date
cust_1      ref003              
cust_2      tran001             
cust_3      ref002              
cust_4      tran019             
cust_5      tran001             
cust_6      chq005              
cust_7      tran019
```

**Output Table - Payment_Confirmations**

```
CustomerID  Payment_No Match_Status   Payment_date
cust_1      ref003      TRUE          12-Nov-19
cust_2      tran001     TRUE          11-Nov-19
cust_3      ref002      TRUE          11-Nov-19
cust_4      tran019     FALSE         FALSE
cust_5      tran001     TRUE          11-Nov-19
cust_6      chq005      TRUE          11-Nov-19
cust_7      tran019     FALSE         FALSE
```

Comment: So, basically, you need to check if `Payment_No` from `Payment_Confirmation` matches with `ranNo` or `RefNo` or `ChequeNo` in `PaymentDetails?`

Comment: yes and than update the status and fetch date.. Thanks

Comment: Why does your `Payment_No` column contain *both* transaction numbers and reference numbers? That doesn't make a lot of sense. These are different things, they ought to be in different columns.

Comment: @Tomalak , Payment_No can have either of 3 refno or tran no or , check no,, also note same Payment_No value can be used for multiple customer... cust_2 and cust_5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

**Table Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE Payment_Details(
  Payment_Date DATETIME,
  TranNo VARCHAR(20),
  RefNo VARCHAR(20),
  ChequeNo VARCHAR(20));

 INSERT INTO Payment_Details VALUES
('11-Nov-19','tran001','ref001','chq001'),
('11-Nov-19','tran001','ref002','chq005'),
('12-Nov-19','tran003','ref003','chq007'),
('13-Nov-19','tran017','ref001','chq005');

 CREATE TABLE Payment_Confirmations(
  CustomerId VARCHAR(20),
  Payment_No VARCHAR(20),
  Match_Status VARCHAR(20),
  Payment_date DATETIME);

INSERT INTO Payment_Confirmations(CustomerId,Payment_No) VALUES
('cust_1','ref003'),
('cust_2','tran001'),
('cust_3','ref002'),
('cust_4','tran019'),
('cust_5','tran001'),
('cust_6','chq005'),
('cust_7','tran019');
```

**SQL Query:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.CustomerID,
    A.Payment_No,
    CASE WHEN B.ChequeNo IS NULL THEN 'FALSE' ELSE 'TRUE' END Match_Status,
    IFNULL(b.Payment_date,'FALSE') Payment_date
FROM Payment_Confirmations A
LEFT JOIN Payment_Details B ON A.Payment_No=B.TranNo OR A.Payment_No=B.RefNo OR A.Payment_No=B.ChequeNo;
```

Check the result in the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/9b91b/6)

Comment: Thanks Dinesh,,, tran001 used 2 times for different customers and total customer count is 7....your query has created 2 rows. for same customer for trann001......cust_2  tran001  TRUE  11-Nov-19
....................cust_2  tran001  TRUE  11-Nov-19.. entry for cust_5  tran001  TRUE...... does not exist .....and shifted 1 cell up so status is showing till customer 6....